# How iPhone 5 + iOS6 will decide if an app must be run in letterbox mode

Tags: iphone, ios6

How the iOS6 decides if the app must be run in letterbox/compatibility mode on iPhone 5?
Is this a build settings parameter (like the "Targeted device family")?
Or all apps build against the latest SDK MUST support iPhone 5 screen size?
Or the app will be run in letterbox mode is there is not a 1136x640 Default.png splashscreen ?
Or what else?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The app will run in letterbox mode if there is no 1136x640 Default.png splashscreen.

The image must be called Default-568h@2x.png (if your splashscreen is Default.png in your Info.plist)

Comment: The image must be called Default-568h@2x.png (if your splashscreen is Default.png in your Info.plist)

Comment: This wont make the VCs extend

Comment: At first this didn't work for me. Then I built clean, and pushed to my iPhone 5 after removing the previous build from the phone, and it finally worked.

Comment: This isn't working for my game developed using the **Sparrow Framework**. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi. Actually, it does work, but only if I install the app via **Testflight**. It doesn't work from Xcode. Weirdest sh*t ever. It jeopardized a delivery. :/

Comment: idStar's comment is important. I had the same issue until I cleaned everything - must be a cached copy of Default-568h@2x.png lying around somewhere.

Comment: What if all LaunchScreens are in an asset by now? Do I need to name the Asset's images like that? They currently have custom names.

Comment: Edit: It looked liked I had to put it as a separate Bundle Resource image to it. Retarded...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add IOS8 specific splash screen too. In my case i had 1136x640 Default.png splashscreen but you need to select launch screen  and select orientation as shown below

[image]

This worked for me. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try adding the splashscreen (special because I didn't have any image by the time), but instead just went to the

> Target General settings -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Launch
>   Images Source

and created a new catalog. Didn't add any image to it, just run the application and the black bars were gone.

Hope this helps anyone.