# Wrong screen size returned for iPhone 5 simulator

Tags: ios, ios6, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How iPhone 5 + iOS6 will decide if an app must be run in letterbox mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode)

I'm using:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

to get screen size.

The returned value is {0,0, 320, 480} for iPhone 5 on iOS simulator. Because of this my OpenGL viewport is smaller than the screen and I have 2 black stripes. I can't try at this moment the code on device.

Is there some workaround to get correct screen size?

I must mention that I'm using same project for several years(since iPhone 3G).

Comment: Have you added the Default-568h@2x.png file to your project?

Comment: @No, but why should code depend on some file added/not added to the project?

Comment: Because that's how Apple designed it.

Comment: @0x7fffffff This is so... weird...

Comment: Ha yeah, I get where you're coming from!

Comment: Because if you haven't added the image, it means you haven't designed the app for the new layout. If you then try and get the screen size and it gives you the actual screensize - you won't have prepared for handling it.

Comment: @Abizern I understand the motivation behind this, but the solution is not straith forward. A better solution(in my oppinion) would be to add a new tag in the plist file for this. If the tag is missing, the app is designed for pre-iphone 5 devices, else...

Comment: Then if you want to have a compatible app you need to set the tag __and__ add you will still need the default screen at the new size? Two places? Just because it makes your implementation a bit harder there is not need to make things more complicated for the rest of us.

Comment: @Abizern In programming every name should mean eaxactly what it says - Default-568h@2x.png is a picture that is displayed on the screen for iPhone 5, a tag in settings is for enabling iPhone 5 screen size. There are 2 different things...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add Default-568h@2x.png in project.

Comment: If you believe a post is a duplicate flag it, don't post possible duplicate in an answer.

Comment: Should I delete this answer?

Comment: I don't think that is necessary because you do still give the correct answer, just letting you know for the future.

Comment: Ok. I will take care of it.