# Black bar showing in iPhone5 When Migrate app icons to an asset catalog

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5

Once i migrate my app icon to an asset catalog i saw the block bar in the launching image as well as all the screen in iPhone5 before migration app was correctly appeared.let me know if you found cause of this problem

Answer (score 0):

To keep letterboxing from happening on your iPhone 5, You need to make certain that there's a "`Default-568h@2x.png`" file in your asset catalog.

[This related question talks a bit more about the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode).