# App runs in iPhone 4 size on iPhone 5 Simulator and Device

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator

When I run my app from Xcode 5.0.2 on an iPhone 5 simulator or device, it runs it at the iPhone 4 height although I already specified 4" screen in Storyboard.

Can't attach an image because of lack of reputation, but there is black space on top and bottom of the app while running.

Comment: Did you add an iPhone5-sized launch image?

Comment: we need more information.  Can you post your viewDelegate viewDidLoad code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Sorry, I tried searching for related posts but I guess I didn't search hard enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a correctly sized (1136x640) splash screen image file, named "`Default-568h@2x.png`".

More info can be [found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the default splash screen files!

Answer (score 0):

When you build your app, on the top left it should say iPhone Retina (3.5-inch).  Change it to iPhone Retina (4-inch)

Comment: The problem was that I forgot to include default splash screen files. Thanks though!