# Simulate 3.5" iPhone screen on iPhone 5 or iPad?

Tags: iphone, simulator, iphone-4

I'm looking for a way to test my app on a 3.5" screen (e.g., iPhone 4S), as my test devices are an iPhone 5 (4") and iPad Air.  Is there a way to do this?  I've investigated the simulator, but as the app uses the music library, I've hit a bit of a dead end there.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think the simulator is fine for what you want to do. Only visual changes will differ on a 3.5" screen. The music library will behave the same way on any screen size. You can test the UI in the simulator, and test the audio behavior on your device. There's no way to simulate a 3.5" screen on a 4" device.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @rdurand!  Most of the app's views are only visible once a song has been selected, hence my troubles.

Comment: I understand, sorry but as @RobertVojta said, there's no other way than keeping your old devices !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just delete the splash screens for iPhone 5 and up (called Retina 4-inch).

The App will run as letterbox app with the dimension of a iPhone 4/4S.

see [How iPhone 5 + iOS6 will decide if an app must be run in letterbox mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode)

[image: XcodeTargetSettings]

Comment: Thanks!  Though I couldn't quite get this to work, it does make sense and the link was useful.  I ended up simply revising my code to "simulate" a song choice, so that I could see all the app's views.  Time to submit the app. :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't do this, there's no option for this. You should keep your old devices if you do want to support them. Without them, it's quite hard to test all these things and it's a roulette ... I do this for a long time and I'm still seeing different behavior on different devices, even with the same iOS version. My only advice is - keep them if you do want to support them in your app.