# Iphone Simulator Xcode 6 on IOS 8 visualize two black bars

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

I have tried new app in Xcode 6 and not use storyboard. But when I have ran the app, with Iphone 5,5s,6 and 6 plus, in Iphone Simulator visualize two black bars on the top and below. Only Iphone 4s there aren't black bars.
Do you have an idea to resolve my problem?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I hade the same problems. I used "Cmd-

Comment: possible duplicate of [How iPhone 5 + iOS6 will decide if an app must be run in letterbox mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode)

Comment: I have added Default-568h@2x.png..Now it's ok

Comment: I added all the launch images of different sizes to assets folder. Still I see black bar on the top and below.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a Default-568h@2x.png image file that is 640x1136 to your project. I added an all black one that was in an older project. I didn't have to set anything else, which was nice. If you are building for iOS8 and later you can just use the LaunchScreen.xib instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using jpg pictures for the default. Even though I had the correct file names and resolutions, it didn't work.
Switching from jpg to png solved it.

Answer (score -2):

If you designed the app so that its views had the "old" screen size, and didn't design them to be responsive to different screen sizes, then the phone will add the black bars (known as a "letterbox", I think).

Comment: I have only added a file xib for Iphone and if you see the second image posted the size width is 320 and height is 568 the resolution of Iphone 5s.