# App running on iphone6 and iphone6+ leaving black space on top and bottom

Tags: ios, xcode

So I am trying to get my app to run on the simulator and iPhone and my app is only taking up part of the screen. It is leaving a about 45 pixels on top and bottom in black. Its like the space where a navbar and tabbar would be?

Why is the app not filling up the entire screen?

I saw this but this isn't the issue.
[Iphone Simulator Xcode 6 on IOS 8 visualize two black bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440467/iphone-simulator-xcode-6-on-ios-8-visualize-two-black-bars)

The app was running fine on my iphone 6+ but I swapped out all the app icons in the assets folder. Now its showing the black bars. I guessing its the launch image?

Comment: Sounds like it is running in the "classic" iPhone 4 3.5-inch mode. You need to explicitly state support for 4, 4.7, and 5.5-inch screen modes.

Comment: And yes, you do that by providing properly sized launch images.

Comment: That is great that you marked this a duplicate. You should show a link as this is a dead end now.  I do have properly sized launched images.