# Weird space in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, xcode6.1

I just ran a demo app on iOS 7 target, this is what I get:

[image]

I'm using a storyboard and it looks well in iOS8. Constraints are correct.

I already checked e.g.
[UITableView is starting with an offset in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios-7)

but the issue in this case is the whole thing, incl. status bar has the offset, no idea what this is. I played around with the layout settings of the view controller in the storyboard without any effect.

I also created a brand new (single view) project, ran it without changing anything, got the same issue. Don't know what can go wrong in a new project concerning autolayout as I can't set any constraints in the root view controller's view...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try adding a "`Default-568h@2x.png`" launch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404699/how-iphone-5-ios6-will-decide-if-an-app-must-be-run-in-letterbox-mode) to keep your iOS 7 device from running the app in Letterbox mode.

[What Apple *really* wants you to do is use Auto-layout](http://www.willowtreeapps.com/development-blog/what-to-expect-when-you-are-expecting-ios-8/) (see point 1 in the linked blog), which is what I suspect your demo app isn't doing.

Comment: I'm using autolayout... set constraints for everything... it works correctly in iOS8.

Comment: I just created a new single view project with the latest version of XCode (6.1), didn't do anything, ran it in 7.1 Simulator and got the same issue. There doesn't seem to be anything I can do with autolayout, as there's only the root viewcontroller's view and I can't set constraints.

Comment: Well, the splash image helps. Weird fix though.